# Cordova - Geolocation seems very unstable on different devices

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation

I have created a mobile app with cordova. This app uses the GPS location of the device. Now the issue is the cordova geolocation plugin seems not to be working on other devices especially on the nexus 7. See sample function below.

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
     //something here
 }, location_error, {timeout: 60000, enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 3600000});
```

I tried a lot of solutions like setting timeout and enabling high accuracy. And the weirdest part is, when i restart the device geolocation works!

Does anyone have any solution for this, or any alternative?

Comment: Yep, we have had the same issue. It seems extremely unstable this plugin

Comment: were you able to solved it?

Comment: nope, still looking for a long term solution. We get a lot of timeouts, other errors include long and lat = 0, Error 3 time out, and if highaccuracy = false we get Error code 2.

Comment: the geolocation plugin doesn't use any java code, it really uses the webview geolocation, so it will deppend on the device, android version and device vendor, it they implemented the geolocation correctly or not. So, there is nothing you can do, maybe search for another plugin or use an old version were it still included java code to handle geolocation

Comment: why is the maximumAge so high in your example? That permits the geolocation service to send you an older (and likely less accurate) location.